# How to make Oracle keep the case of identifiers as they appear in the query?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, case-sensitive

I want to use a php library that uses PDO. And I want to use an Oracle database with it.

The problem is that authors of that library use unquoted identifiers in their queries, e.g.:

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from some_table where some_column = :some_column');
$statement->execute(['some_column' => 'some value']);
$result = $statement->fetch(\PDO:FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result['some_other_column'];
```

In this case, Oracle converts the case of identifiers to UPPER, but authors assume the case is lower, therefore an `undefined index` php error occurs.

How do I bypass this?

UPD. I tried to use lower case when creating database objects, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "some_table"
(
    "some_column"       VARCHAR(10),
    "some_other_column" VARCHAR(10)
);
```

- but in this case, Oracle raises an error when executing the `SELECT` statement above, because identifiers in it are converted to UPPER case, while object names are in lower case.

UPD 2.

I shouldn't edit the source code of the third party library - have to configure somehow my environment and connection: Oracle, PHP, PDO.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but - as far as Oracle is concerned - if you want to keep letter case, enclose those *identifiers* into double quotes. See if it helps.

Comment: [PDO::CASE_NATURAL](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdo+oracle+case)

Comment: @Littlefoot how do I do that if I'm not the developer of that library? Are you suggesting to overwrite their code in every place they use an SQL query?

Comment: Uh, no. As I said, I don't know PHP, I have no idea how it actually works. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, IMO, pdo does already use case_natural - this is why it returns the result in upper case. but you gave me a good idea - I'll try to force it use lower case (because authors of library use lower case) - maybe it'll help

Comment: @Littlefoot the problem here is not in php, the problem is that I should not modify the code of a third party library, and am looking for solution that doesn't require that :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you so much, your suggestion (modified a little - using actually `PDO:CASE_LOWER`) works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my case, thanks to `Your Common Sense`'s comment.

When initializing the library, I pass it a PDO object - I've configured it to always use lower case, by the following code:

```php
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
];
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
init3rdPartyLibrary($connection);
```

Because of this, the keys of the `$result` variable returned by `$statement->fetch()` are now lowercase and therefore the library works as expected by its authors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use lower case identifiers then, as you wrote in the question, you need to double quote them in Oracle:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "some_table"
(
    "some_column"       VARCHAR(10),
    "some_other_column" VARCHAR(10)
);
```

If you have used case-sensitive identifiers then you will **ALWAYS** need to quote them every time they are used. So your SQL statement in PHP should be:

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from "some_table" where "some_column" = :some_column');
```

Once you have quoted them there then the identifiers will match the values in the database and the result set returned should also have lower-case column identifiers.

> How do I bypass this?

From Oracle's [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) documentation:

> ## Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.
>
> You can use either quoted or nonquoted identifiers to name any database object.

...

> 9. Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

Which means that you cannot bypass this in Oracle as this is the way Oracle is designed to behave. You either quote the identifiers (everywhere they are used) and can have lower-case identifiers or Oracle will implicitly convert the unquoted identifiers to upper-case.